# Sidecar Colour Calibration

Tags: display, color, sidecar

When I use sidecar on an iPad, I notice that the colour might need calibrating. However, in MacOS settings, I do not see the option to choose a colour profile.

Is there a way of adjusting the colour of the sidecar somehow? It does not need to be 100% accurate - it suffices to just roughly change the balance of RGB and some other simple things.